# Canadian accepting money electronically from Americans

Tags: canada, money-transfer, electronic-payment

What are some methods I can receive money from someone in the States if Paypal is out of the question? I run a small electronic cigarette company, and I'm finding it hard to find an easy method to do business with Americans. Canada has Interac e-transfer which is what I use for my home customers, but is there something similar for America?

Comment: Have you looked into accepting credit cards? When we did so (20+ years ago) it was trivially easy and cost us only $8/mo plus the commission on the transactions. We arranged it through the bank where we had the business account. Apparently it's much harder for US businesses, which may be why you're not considering it. Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a version of Interac available in the U.S., but there are alternative ways to receive money:

- Cheque. The problem with mailed cheques is that they take time to deliver, and time to clear. If you ship your wares before the cheque has cleared and the cheque is bad, you're out the merchandise.
- COD. How this works is you place a COD charge on your item at the post office in the amount you charge the customer. The post office delivers the package on the other end when the customer pays. The post office pays you at the time you send the package. There is a fee for this, talk to your local post office or visit the Canada Post website.
- Money order. Have your U.S. customers send an International Money Order, not a Domestic Money Order. Domestic money orders can only be cashed at a U.S. post office. The problem here is again delivery time, and verifying your customer sent an International Money Order. It can be a pain to have to send back a Domestic Money Order to a customer explaining what they have to do to pay you, even more painful if you don't catch the error before shipping your wares.
- Credit Card. There are a number of companies offering credit card processing that are much cheaper than a bank. PayPal, Square, and Intuit are three such companies offering these services. After I did my investigations I found Square to be the best deal for me. Please do your own research on these companies (and banks!) and find out which one makes the most sense for you. Some transaction companies may forbid the processing of payment for e-cig materials as they my be classed as tobacco.